# Dynamically updating overlay icon to Command usning IElementUpdater is not working in eclipse Compitability mode

Tags: eclipse, handler, decorator, jface, e4

Recently we have migrated from Eclipse 3.x to Eclipse 4.x and now were are running our Eclipse 3.x code in compatibility mode

I have a handler implementing `IElementUpdater` and overrided `updateElement` as shown below:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void updateElement(final UIElement element, final Map parameters) {
    Image filterImage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage(ICECImageConstants.FILTER_CO);
    ImageDescriptor addcoDescriptor = AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin("com.myCompany.ui.common",
                                                                                 "icons/decorator_ovr.png");
    if (null != filterImage && null != addcoDescriptor) {
        DecorationOverlayIcon decorationOverlayIcon = new DecorationOverlayIcon(filterImage,
                                                                                addcoDescriptor,
                                                                                IDecoration.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        element.setIcon(decorationOverlayIcon);

    }

}
```

plugin.xml

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="toolbar:com.myCompany.ui.common.bauteilView">
     <command
           commandId="com.myCompany.ui.common.filter.project"
           icon="icons/filter_co.gif "
           id="%command.name.project.filter"
           label="%command.name.project.filter"
           style="push">
     </command>
```

This code is working in Eclipse 3.x but not in Eclipse 4.x, anybody has any idea how to go with this.

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Is `updateElement` being called? When did you expect it to be called?

Comment: not working means the 'decorationOverlayIcon 'is not displayed in the UI. and 'updateElement' is getting called and i tried 'commandService.refreshElements(#Command ID#)' also  but the icon is not displaying

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `UIElement.setIcon` method will only work when it is possible to determine a URL for the image. Since this isn't possible for `DecorationOverlayIcon` your code doesn't work.

Using a prebuilt image with the base image and overlay obtained using `AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin` should work since this will have a URL.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back . Regarding prebuilt image, I have tried and it works but `DecorationOverlayIcon`  was working with Eclipse 3.x versions and we are facing this issue only after Eclipse RCP e4 migration

Comment: The underlying code has changed for Eclipse 4 and a few things that worked on Eclipse 3 no longer work on Eclipse 4. You will have to change your code.